# A small problem to solve in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

Can you please try this in VBScript:
You got a text file with several currency amounts, every one in one line on following format:

```
DESCRIPTION Date Amount

McDonalds 2011-01-01 20.00
Clothing Store 2011-01-02 30.00
```

Try to build a program to read that text file and sum all values found in there.

Answer (score 2):

First (pedestrian) attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName( "..\data\expenses.csv" )
WScript.Echo goFS.OpenTextFile( sFSpec ).ReadAll()
WScript.Echo "---------"
Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile( sFSpec )
Dim nSum  : nSum     = 0.0
Dim sLine : sLine    = tsIn.ReadLine()
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
   Dim aFields : aFields = Split( sLine, "," )
   If 2 = UBound( aFields ) Then
      nSum = nSum + CDbl( aFields( 2 ) ) ' en_us, ...
'     nSum = nSum + CDbl( Replace( aFields( 2 ), ".", "," ) ) ' locale de_de, ...
   End If
Loop
tsIn.Close
WScript.Echo "Sum:", nSum
```

Output:

```
lineLoop - sum values (line loop)
---------------------------------------------------
"DESCRIPTION","Date","Amount"
"McDonalds",2011-01-01,20.00
"Clothing Store",2011-01-02,30.00
"paying programmer",2011-07-09,47.11

---------
Sum: 97.11
===================================================
xpl.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [ 0,01563 secs ]
```

Second attempt (using a regular expression):

```
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName( "..\data\expenses.csv" )
Dim sAll   : sAll   = goFS.OpenTextFile( sFSpec ).ReadAll()
WScript.Echo sAll
WScript.Echo "---------"
Dim reAmount : Set reAmount = New RegExp
reAmount.Global    = True
reAmount.MultiLine = True
reAmount.Pattern   = ",(\d+\.\d+)\r$" 
Dim nSum     : nSum         = 0.0
Dim oMTS     : Set oMTS     = reAmount.Execute( sAll )
Dim oMT
For Each oMT In oMTS
    nSum = nSum + CDbl( oMT.Submatches(0) ) ' en_us, ...
'   nSum = nSum + CDbl( Replace( oMT.Submatches(0), ".", "," ) ) ' locale de_de, ...
Next
WScript.Echo "Sum:", nSum
```

Third attempt (ADO/Text driver):

schema.ini:

```
[expenses.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=YYYY-MM-DD
CharacterSet=ANSI
Col1=DESCRIPTION CHAR
Col2=Date DATE
Col3=Amount FLOAT
```

Code:

```
Const adClipString = 2

Dim sTDir : sTDir    = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName( "..\data" )
Dim oTDb  : Set oTDb = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Dim sCS   : sCS      = Join( Array( _
   "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
 , "Data Source=" & sTDir _
 , "Extended Properties=" & Join( Array( _
      "text" _
    ), ";" ) _
), ";" )
oTDB.Open sCS
WScript.Echo oTDb.Execute( "SELECT * FROM [expenses.csv]" ) _
  .GetString( adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "" )
WScript.Echo oTDb.Execute( "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS [Sum] FROM [expenses.csv]" ) _
  .GetString( adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "" )
WScript.Echo oTDb.Execute( "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS [Sum] FROM [expenses.csv] WHERE MONTH([Date]) = 7" ) _
  .GetString( adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "" )
oTDb.Close
```

Output:

```
McDonalds       01.01.2011      20
Clothing Store  02.01.2011      30
paying programmer       09.07.2011      47,11

97,11

47,11

===================================================
xpl.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [ 0,23438 secs ]
```

or - with a bit of additional work:

```
useAdoText - sum values (ADO/Text driver)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM [expenses.csv]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|DESCRIPTION      |Date      |Amount|
|McDonalds        |01.01.2011|    20|
|Clothing Store   |02.01.2011|    30|
|paying programmer|09.07.2011| 47,11|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS [Sum] FROM [expenses.csv]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sum  |
|97,11|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS [Sum] FROM [expenses.csv] WHERE MONTH([Date]) = 7
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sum  |
|47,11|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================
xpl.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [ 0,25000 secs ]
```